# why is this Radio type symbols are showing in my terminal : did i do something wrong with my vs code or i have never noticed this new update?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[why is this    Radio  type symbols are showing  in my terminal  : did i do something wrong with my vs code  or  i have never noticed  this new update?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKwRM.png)

i hope i get answer :) thx  and i am new to stackoverflow so idk how this works too

why is this    Radio  type symbols are showing  in my terminal  : did i do something wrong with my vs code  or  i have never noticed  this new update?